# Excel won't close after running macro

Tags: excel, vba

I've searched extensively for answers to this, but I can't find anything specific.  I have an excel workbook, and a number of macros sitting behind it.  The macros are used to do a few database queries, and a user-defined function to run an iterative calculation.  The database queries use class modules, but I am careful to set them to nothing.

Anyway - if I open the workbook and play around with "normal" worksheet functions, when I hit "X" to close, the workbook asks me if I want to save changes, and then exits.  All very normal.  However, if I run the macro that imports the data, then when I try to close the workbook, I get the "wait" donut, and it flickers a bit.  I can select other tabs (so it is not a modal dialog holding it out).

I open the VBA editor, and the donut flickers extensively, like it is trying to do something in the background.  In the VBA editor, usually I can hit the "Stop" or "Pause" button.  Sometimes that doesn't work.  When it does, the "Want to save your changes?" dialog appears, and once I select my option, the workbook closes.

I've tried repairing the workbook.  I've tried exporting and deleting all the macros, then reimporting them.  I've tried fixing "Workbook_BeforeClose" to enable and disable display alerts, and set the "saved" flag.  Nothing works.

Any other suggestions?  It's driving me nuts!

Edit - Salient Code:

Edit 2:  Further Update:
There is a user-defined function that I use to process the data from the query, and return the values as an array.  Code is as follows:

```
Public Function AllocateSPN(mda As Double, DQs As Range, MaxDQs As Range) As Variant
'//Input should be a range that has one row (and 10 columns)
If DQs.Rows.Count <> 1 Or MaxDQs.Rows.Count <> 1 Or DQs.Columns.Count <> MaxDQs.Columns.Count Then
    AllocateSPN = "Check input! 1 row and Dqs must match Maxdq Columns"
    Exit Function
End If

Dim colCount As Long
colCount = DQs.Columns.Count

Dim output() As Variant
ReDim output(1 To 1, 1 To colCount) As Variant

Dim sumMaxDQ As Long
Dim sumDQ As Long

Dim col As Long
For col = 1 To colCount
    sumDQ = sumDQ + DQs.Cells(1, col).Value
    sumMaxDQ = sumMaxDQ + MaxDQs.Cells(1, col).Value
Next col

If sumMaxDQ <= mda Then
    For col = 1 To colCount
        output(1, col) = MaxDQs.Cells(1, col).Value
    Next col
    AllocateSPN = output
    Exit Function
End If

Dim thisAllocation As Double
Dim thisDQ As Double
Dim surplus As Double
For col = 1 To colCount
    thisDQ = DQs.Cells(1, col).Value
    thisAllocation = mda * thisDQ / sumDQ
    If thisAllocation > MaxDQs.Cells(1, col).Value Then
        surplus = surplus + (thisAllocation - MaxDQs.Cells(1, col).Value)
        thisAllocation = MaxDQs.Cells(1, col).Value
        output(1, col) = thisAllocation
    Else
        output(1, col) = thisAllocation
    End If
Next col

If surplus = 0 Then
    AllocateSPN = output
    Exit Function
Else
    Dim modDQ() As Double
    ReDim modDQ(1 To colCount) As Double
    Dim modDQsum As Double
    While surplus > 0.1
        ReDim modDQ(1 To colCount) As Double
        modDQsum = 0
        For col = 1 To colCount
            If output(1, col) < MaxDQs(1, col).Value Then
                modDQ(col) = DQs(1, col).Value
                modDQsum = modDQsum + DQs(1, col).Value
            Else
                modDQ(col) = 0
            End If
        Next col

        Dim maxAdditional As Double
        For col = 1 To colCount
            thisDQ = modDQ(col)
            thisAllocation = surplus * thisDQ / modDQsum
            maxAdditional = MaxDQs.Cells(1, col).Value - output(1, col)

            If thisAllocation > maxAdditional Then
                output(1, col) = MaxDQs.Cells(1, col).Value
            Else
                output(1, col) = output(1, col) + thisAllocation
            End If
        Next col
        surplus = mda
        For col = 1 To colCount
            surplus = surplus - output(1, col)
        Next col
    Wend
    AllocateSPN = output
End If
End Function
```

Edit Again:

OK - seems I've "Fixed" it, but don't know how.  I found that when I deleted the UDF from the sheet, the problem didn't happen.  Figured it was an issue with that.  However, when I changed input data manually in the sheet for the UDF, the problem also didn't happen.

So... It appeared that it was an issue with the interaction between the Database call code and the UDF (the database call populates cells that the UDF then uses as an input).

I added `application.Calculation = xlManual` and `application.screenUpdating=false` at the start of the data download, turned them back on at the end (normally I do that for efficiency anyway).  Seems to have resolved the issue!

Comment: If you hit Pause, what code does it stop on?

Comment: No code whatsoever!

Comment: Offhand, this sounds like you are trying to connect to a DB Service with a zero (infinite) timeout, which does behave like this if the service is down or non-existent. However, that may not be the only possibility.

Comment: Post your code please.  Most likely you disabled something in your code that's causing this.

Comment: OK - added it.  Difficult because the library that I am using for the queries is fairly large and complex (It handles connections to numerous databases, and also includes handlers to prevent SQL injection).  I haven't posted those because I use the library in several other workbooks without this type of issue, so I'm happy enough that the library is working.  It is an Oracle database, and it does have a timeout incidentally.  And the error is happening even though the code is executing correctly.

Comment: Have your tried a parital import of the macros after the repair or after starting with a clean workbook? (First step: 5 chunks = 5 parts / Second step 10 chunks / 10 parts of code)

Comment: Or you might try with some kind of "binary search" approach: two chunks of code! Does the problem occur with only part 1 of the code? Does the problem occur with only part 2 of the code? => Then you cut your code into "working" pieces and such find where the problem is!

Comment: I am not seeing the timeout settings here.  I think you shold set a breakpoint at the beginning and then step through the code to see where it hangs.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: It's not hanging in running this code.  This code runs fine, executes fully and gives me the data I'm expecting.  It is only when trying to close the workbook afterwards that there is any issue.  Before I hit "Close" the workbook is otherwise fully responsive and functioning.

Comment: You say _I've tried fixing "Workbook_BeforeClose"_ If you have `BeforeClose` I suggest you post that code.

Comment: OK - I've narrowed the problem somewhat.  I'll update my post above.

Comment: See update - think it is fixed.  Problem with interaction between UDF and macro updating data.